# Loading multiple views from codeigniter using jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.menuitem').click(function() {
                            var link = $(this), url = link.attr("href");
                                var newDiv = '<div></div>';
                                $("#content_pane").append(newDiv);
                                newDiv.load(url);
                                return false; // prevent default link-behavior
                    });

 });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <li><a class="menuitem" href="inspiration">Inspiration</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
    <div id="content_pane">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is semi working, when I click the button a new div id created but it prints out load(url) on the page instead of showing the page content that it is supposed to be loading does any one have any tips?

Comment: I noticed that you edited your question (taking out the load(url) from inside the <div>'s). Does it still print out `load(url)`?

Comment: no it just acts a normal link now, doing my head i know this possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var link = $( this ), url = link.attr( "href" );
var newDiv = $( document.createElement( 'div' ) );
$( "#content_pane" ).append( newDiv );
newDiv.load( url );
return false;
```

Comment: uncommented the line and sorted my vars out...it just navigates me to the page as normal, it should load the content into my current page